# How can i write SQL update query with where clause in Entity Framework in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I know that for update a model in EF i must get model then change it then dbContext.SaveChanges()
but sometimes in my Asp.net mvc project , i want update a field in my table and i don't know it 's id  and must be get it with where clause.
but i don't want connect twice to database , because in ADO.net i can write:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Field3 = "NewValue" WHERE Active = 1
```

and now i want write a linq to sql for EF that work like that.
Is exist any way for that?
thanks

Comment: Kindly check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918249/how-to-update-a-list-of-multiple-records-same-as-normal-sql-update-query-using-e/56918784#56918784

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't.
EF is ORM, that means, you need to work with separate objects (update them one by one).

Look at [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) library for that:

```
//update all tasks with status of 1 to status of 2
context.Tasks
    .Where(t => t.StatusId == 1)
    .Update(t => new Task { StatusId = 2 });
```

For EF Core: [EntityFramework-Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus)

Comment: at some point it started to stop working? The License seems to be a commercial one? https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.Extended

Comment: `NO LONGER SUPPORTED SINCE 2015`

Comment: @Toolkit and that's why I added version for EF Core in my answer in the last line.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the raw query function in EF.

```
var query = "UPDATE MyTable SET Field3 = 'NewValue' WHERE Active = 1";
using (var context = new YourContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query); 
}
```

Comment: thanks. i knew it , but i want to use EF and linq benefits

Comment: what you want, then, is to use your relational database like a relational database - and that's not what EF (or ORM at large) is about. Sadly. 

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can do as of EF 7, take a look at [Efficient Updating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating?tabs=ef7) for more details.

To do what you're looking for would be

```
dbContext.MyTable
    .Where(mt => mt.Active == 1)
    .ExecuteUpdate(mt => mt.SetProperty(e => e.Field3, e => "New Value"));
```

Unlike older solutions, this will operate as a single database operation. The [Efficient Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating?tabs=ef7) article also discusses other uses.