# How to update a list of multiple records same as normal SQL Update query using entity framework core?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Normally in SQL we can write this query `UPDATE users SET isAdult = 1 WHERE age >18`

I want to apply some edit to all rows that satisfy some condition in entity framework core.

I wrote this code and I got an error

```
List<User> usersList = _context.Users.Where(u => u.age >18).ToList();
usersList.ForEach(a =>
                {
                    a.isAdult = 1;
                });
_context.Entry(usersList).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

The error is

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'List' was not
>   found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.GetOrCreateEntry(Object
>   entity)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.EntryWithoutDetectChanges[TEntity](TEntity
>   entity)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Entry[TEntity](TEntity entity)

I made this update but I want to know if this is the best way.

```
List<Users> usersList = _context.Users.Where(u => u.age >18).ToList();
usersList.ForEach(a =>
                {
                    a.isAdult = 1;
                    _context.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;
                     _context.SaveChanges();
                });
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to modify the state yourself.  EF will do that for you.

Comment: Also you dont want to do the save changes inside the loop. It does have some performance hits calling it that way. Do it after the foreach.

Comment: I tried to call it after the loop and the in the first code snippet .. you can see the error :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error was because the list isn't defined as an EF Entity.

In the end, you don't need to modify the state youself.

```
List<User> usersList = _context.Users.Where(u => u.age >18).ToList(); 
usersList.ForEach(a => { a.isAdult = 1; });
 _context.SaveChanges();
```