# Update A Table From A List

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two tables. One of them is Customers which is in the database, the other one is ChangedCustomers, which comes from the user. I write the updated model, I guess there is something missing.

```
public async Task<int> UpdateCustomers (IENumerable<ChangedCustomers> changedCustomers
{
  foreach(var item in changedCustomers)
  {
    _context.Customers.Updaate (new Customers()
     {
       CustomerName=item.CustomerName,
       CustomerAddress=item.CustomerAddress
     });
  }
return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

In Method I am not saying something like "update that row when Id values in Customers and ChangedCustomers tables are equal". I need this but I can't. How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a list of multiple records same as normal SQL Update query using entity framework core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918249/how-to-update-a-list-of-multiple-records-same-as-normal-sql-update-query-using-e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying update the row by adding a new row? Thats what it looks like. If you want to update a specific row, you will need to fetch that row, then update the values.

```
foreach (var item in changedCustomers)
{
    var customer = _context.Customers
          .FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerId == item.CustomerId);

    if (customer != null)
    {
        customer.CustomerName = item.CustomerName;
        customer.CustomerAddress = item.CustomerAddress;
    }
    else
    {
        customer = new Customer
        {
            CustomerName = item.CustomerName,
            CustomerAddress = item.CustomerAddress
        }
        _context.Add(customer);
    }
}

_context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

`FirstOrDefault()` will retrieve the first value from `_context.Customers` that matches the expression, if it doesn't find any it will default to null. If it is not null then you can make the changes, if it is null, you could add a new value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's general logic that you'd follow to update an existing record which could be placed within your loop:

```
    //Find the entity already tracked based on table key
    var entity = context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(item => item.YourTableID == id);
    
    // Validate entity is not null
    if (entity != null)
    {
        // Make changes to specific field
        entity.Name = "Me";

        // Update entity in it's entirety
        entity = new Customers() { //Your logic here to build the updated entity }        

        // Save changes in database
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just mark the entities as modified and call `SaveChanges`.
Only `UPDATE` sql queries will be executed.
The code in @jaabh answer is very inefficient, since it pre-executes sql-queries SELECT, reading from the database those entities that we already have. This is unnecessary.

```
public async Task<int> UpdateCustomers(IEnumerable<ChangedCustomers> changedCustomers)
{
    foreach (var item in changedCustomers)
    {
        _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```